# Highlight menu parent - CSS & PHP issue

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am drafting a new website, and having some issues with highlighting the parent page when on a child page. I will explain what system I am using, and then what I have tried.

For a single top level item, I use:

PHP:

```
<?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>
```

at the top of the page, followed by:

```
<ul>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == '#') { ?><li class="on">News</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="#">News</a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
```

And for drop downs:

```
<li><a href="#" class="none">About</a>
<ul>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'club.php') { ?><li class="on">Club</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../club.php">Club</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'coaches.php') { ?><li class="on">Coaches</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../coaches.php">Coaches</a></li><?php } ?>    
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'officials.php') { ?><li class="on">Officials</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../officials.php">Officials</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'management.php') { ?><li class="on">Management Team</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../management.php">Management</a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Styled with:

CSS:

```
.nav {
width: 990px;
height: 60px;
}

.nav ul {
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
width: auto;
}

.nav ul li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}

.nav ul li a {
color: #666;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
height: 36px;
width: 110px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 36px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

a.none {
cursor: default;
}

.nav li:hover > a {
background-color: #181d63;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
display: block;

}

.nav li ul li a {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
color: #000;
top: 38px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
}   

.nav li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #CCC;
color: #000;
top: 38px;
text-align: center;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
background-color: #181d63;
}

.on { 
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #181d63;
display: block;
height: 36px;
width: 110px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 36px;
cursor: default;

}

.off { 

}
```

This works well and highlights the page that is open, be that in the top level or drop down. I would like to make it so that being on any of the child pages will also highlight the top level parent.

I have tried:

PHP:

```
<ul>
<li><?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'club.php') { ?><li class="on">About</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="#" class="drop">About</a><?php } ?>
<ul>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'club.php') { ?><li class="on">Club</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../club.php">Club</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'coaches.php') { ?><li class="on">Coaches</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../coaches.php">Coaches</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'officials.php') { ?><li class="on">Officials</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../officials.php">Officials</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'management.php') { ?><li class="on">Management Team</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../management.php">Management</a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And adding the following to the css:

CSS:

```
a.drop {
}

a.drop:hover {
visibility: visible !important;
background-color: #181d63;
}
```

At this point, I run in to two things.

1. Being on the 'club.php' page now highlights the parent.

I'm not sure how to add to the php to incorporate all it's child pages. ('page1', 'page2') doesn't seem to work.

1. Although the parent is now highlighted, that menu item no longer drops down.

I think I need to create an .onchild condition that when applied to a top level parent, still allows a drop down, but I'm really quite stuck on how to go about this, and seem to be deviating ever further from my original code! I am keen to keep this all in PHP and CSS without resorting to jquery if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add child in parent 'if'?

```
<ul>
<li><?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'club.php' || $currentPage == 'coaches.php' || $currentPage == 'officials.php' || $currentPage == 'management.php') { ?><li class="on">About</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="#" class="drop">About</a><?php } ?>
<ul>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'club.php') { ?><li class="on">Club</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../club.php">Club</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'coaches.php') { ?><li class="on">Coaches</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../coaches.php">Coaches</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'officials.php') { ?><li class="on">Officials</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../officials.php">Officials</a></li><?php } ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'management.php') { ?><li class="on">Management Team</li><?php } else { ?><li class="off"><a href="../management.php">Management</a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Or you could use in_array

```
$array = array('club.php', 'coaches.php', 'etc');
if(in_array($currentPage, $array)) { /* do code */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Adding an array worked perfectly! All pages now highlight their parent menu item, solving issue 1. Issue 2 remains. When on a child of a parent menu item, hovering the menu item will not show the drop down.

Comment: Menu is showing but it is beneath other menu. When making dropdown menus you should really use these CSS "codes" for example _nav > ul > li:hover > ul_ otherwise all ul's or li's will have same property or there will be fight between styles. Here is my rushed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6Lp2/ Scroll to te bottom of CSS tab and last 3 styles are mine